# How to iterate list of start index and end index in Python

Tags: python, iteration

Let's say I have a list: `theList = [1, -3, 9, -7, 2, 5, 2, -4, -5]` and want to iterate through them with the given index starting at index 2 and ending with index 6 to print out the list from index 2 to index 6. How would I do this? Thank you.

Comment: list slicing...?

Comment: you can use `range(2, 6, 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

Assuming the desired output is:

9, -7, 2, 5, 2

You can do this with a few different options:

```
theList = [1, -3, 9, -7, 2, 5, 2, -4, -5]
```

With a nifty one liner:

```
print([item for item in theList[2:7]])
->[9, -7, 2, 5, 2]
```

With a one liner in range:

```
print([theList[item] for item in range(2,7)])
->[9, -7, 2, 5, 2]
```

If you want both the index, and the value, you can do it like so:

```
for i, num in enumerate(theList[2:7], start=2):
    print(f"{i}, {num}")
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `theList[start:end+1]` and iterate over it.

```
for item in theList[2:7]:
    print(item)
```